# How to hide navigation pane in embedded PDF viewer control?

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba

**Goal: Trying to provide a embedded preview of a PDF file in a form (first page) without scroll bars, navigation panes etc showing.**

Using Adobes PDF ActiveX control (Class AcroPDF.PDF.1), there are embedded PDF files in the MS Access form.

So far I have

```
pdfControl.src = filePath
pdfControl.setShowToolbar(False) ' hides toolbar (bar along top)
pdfControl.setShowScrollBars(False) ' hides scroll bars since only first page important
pdfControl.setPageMode("none") ' hides bookmarks and thumbs instead of opening by default
```

After this I'm left with just the navigation pane on the left.  Using the object browser I went through the functions, could not see anything explicitly mention navigation panes.

Is there a way to hide the navigation pane from the embedded PDF control?

**Edit**: I've found that you can set a flag to hide the navigation page when opening in a non embedded instance as such

```
Call Shell("'" & applicationPath & "' /A 'navpanes=0&toolbars=0' '" & filePath & "'", vbNormalFocus)
```

But I'm still failing to achieve the same thing while embedded.

**Edit2**: Below is the image where on the left is what I'm trying to get rid of and on the right is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Depending on the license I'm open to using different libraries and controls if there isn't a solution using this control (AcroPDF.dll - Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Library 1.0)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did u find a solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Web Browser Control` instead.
It will use the systems default PDF application to preview the files.

`webBrowserControl.Navigate(filePath & "#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0")`

There are more parameters that can be used to customize the way you want to open the file in the document below

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: This is a pretty bad solution. If you end up executing on a PC with browser in protected mode, the control will start throwing errors.

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
Shell applicationPath & " /A " & Chr(34) & "navpanes=0&toolbars=0" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & filePath & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: Truly appreciate the help.  I read the article but this helps me with opening a window outside, which is not what I want.  I'm trying to do the same behavior with a control inside the form as seen http://i.imgur.com/qi8xXn7.png

Comment: @ashareef it is not recommended to use PDF Preview in Access form itself because whenever Adobe makes version updates you must have to manually update the code as per the adobe updates.
However you have another option, you can use `Web Browser Control` to preview  the PDF files in the access form and this will also eliminate your headache of manually updating the code whenever adobe release updates

Comment: Have a look at the document.. this might help you
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/iac/IACReference.pdf

Comment: I can't accept this answer and award bounty unless you let me edit it to what I've actually used as a result of your suggestion in your comments or you're welcome to post another answer (with `Web Browser Control` and I can award it to that one